# Unable to rotate apache access log

Tags: apache, logging, rotation

I am unable to rotate apache access log despite so many attempts.
Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

**Below is the code snippet.**

1. `httpd.conf (location - /ngs/app/istsvnp/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)`

   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
       LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
       
           LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
       
       CustomLog "|/ngs/app/istsvnp/httpd/bin/rotatelogs /ngs1/app/istsvnp/logs/access_log 86400" combined
2. `logs (access_log) inside logs folder is a symbolic link -`

   istsvnp@dhaka:~/httpd$ ls -lt logs
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 istsvnp istsvnp 22 Apr 18  2012 logs -> /ngs1/app/istsvnp/logs

   istsvnp@dhaka:~/httpd/logs$ ls -lt access_log
   -rw-r----- 1 istsvnp istsvnp 66575435740 Nov 25  2014 access_log
3. File Permission label of rotatelogs is 755.

   istsvnp@dhaka:~/httpd/bin$ stat -c %a rotatelogs
   755

As per the apache link- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html, do not see any issue with syntax.

Currently `access_log` is getting filled up daily @2 GB of data.

Issue might be due to a different filer (logs -> /ngs1/app/istsvnp/logs) (/ngs/app/istsvnp/httpd/logs) where logs are getting written.

Could anyone please let me know if anything I am missing.